# how convert array to object with specific key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a big array with below format

```
 [
    { 
      id: '1', 
      name: "bloh", 
      coordinates: [[51.3888562, 35.7474398], [51.388671,35.7470575],[51.3887346, 35.7470375]]
    },
    {
      id: '2', 
      name: "blohbloh",
      coordinates:  [[51.3888562, 35.7474398],[51.3822271, 35.7444575]]
    }
 ]
```

I want to convert format of coordinates property of all elements to below format

```
{
   id: '1',
   name: "bloh",
   coordinates:[{longitude:51.3888562,latitude: 35.7474398},{longitude:51.3887346,latitude: 35.7470375}]
},

{
   id: '2', 
   name: "blohbloh", 
   coordinates:[{longitude:51.3888562,latitude: 35.7474398},{longitude:51.3822271,latitude: 35.7444575}]
}
```

Comment: The thing you posted is not a valid JSON. You can not have an object that contains a value without a key at the left side. Please, edit your question to include the valid "starting" JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with map:

```js
let input = [{id: '1', name: "bloh", coordinates:  [[51.3888562, 35.7474398], [51.388671,35.7470575],[51.3887346, 35.7470375]]},{id: '2', name: "blohbloh",coordinates:  [[51.3888562, 35.7474398],[51.3822271, 35.7444575]]}];

let result = input.map(({id, name, coordinates}) => {
  return { id, name, coordinates: coordinates.map(([latitude,longitude]) => { return { latitude, longitude}})};
});

console.log("Result: ", result);
```

Comment: more destructure 
return { id, name, coordinates: coordinates.map(([latitude, longitude]) => { return { latitude, longitude}})};

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and then you need to use map to change representation of coordinates from array to object.

You can use following code to convert.

```
var arr=[{id: '1', name: "bloh", coordinates:  [[51.3888562, 35.7474398], [51.388671,35.7470575],[51.3887346, 35.7470375]]},{id: '2', name: "blohbloh",coordinates: [ [51.3888562, 35.7474398],[51.3822271, 35.7444575]]}];
arr.forEach(elm=>elm.coordinates=elm.coordinates.map(c=>({longitude:c[0],latitude:c[1]})));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to copy all properties of the top-level objects in a `rest` variable and map() the coordinates to another format:

```js
const data = [{id: '1', name: "bloh", coordinates:[[51.3888562, 35.7474398], [51.388671,35.7470575],[51.3887346, 35.7470375]]},{id: '2', name: "blohbloh",coordinates:[[51.3888562, 35.7474398],[51.3822271, 35.7444575]]}];

const result = data.map(({ coordinates, ...rest }) =>
  ({
    ...rest,
    coordinates: coordinates.map(([longitude, latitude]) => ({ longitude, latitude }))
  })
);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In any kind of problem you face, first, you should understand what you need to do, and prettier data will always help you to achieve this.

You want to convert this:

```
const original = [{
  id: '1',
  name: "bloh",
  coordinates: [ [51.3888562, 35.7474398],
               [51.388671,35.7470575],
               [51.3887346, 35.7470375] ]
 },
 {
  id: '2',
  name: "blohbloh",
  coordinates:  [ [51.3888562, 35.7474398],
                [51.3822271, 35.7444575] ]
 }
]
```

To this:

```
{
  id: '1',
  name: "bloh",
  coordinates:[
    {longitude:51.3888562,latitude: 35.7474398},
    {longitude:51.3887346,latitude: 35.7470375}
   ]
},
{
  id: '2',
  name: "blohbloh",
  coordinates:[
    {longitude:51.3888562,latitude: 35.7474398},
    {longitude:51.3822271,latitude: 35.7444575}
   ]
}
```

We will use the 'for' loop because it is easier to see what's going on, in my own opinion.

```
for(i in original){
  original[i].coordinates = original[i].coordinates.map(item => {return {
    latitude: item[0], 
    longitude: item[1]}
    })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(original))
```

You can use prettifier  to see your data in more pretty way,for example using this resource:  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Hope this will help.